# Using ssh-keygen with a private key file on NTFS

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I'm attempting to use `ssh-keygen` to read a private key file from a Windows partition, and output the public key.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f private_deploy_key
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for 'spot_private_deploy_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: private_deploy_key
Enter passphrase: 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for 'spot_private_deploy_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: private_deploy_key
load failed
```

Because this is an NTFS filesystem, I can't change the file's permissions:

```
$ chmod 600 spot_private_deploy_key

$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meyerat meyerat 1678 Jul  2 16:28 spot_private_deploy_key
```

Is there a way around this? I realize I *could* copy the file to the ext4 file system my Linux partition is on and run the command there; but is there a better (or perhaps easier) way?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a discussion with this

I had a look at the source code and found this :

> if ((st.st_uid == getuid()) && (st.st_mode & 077) != 0) {
>   error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
>   error("@ WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! @");
>   error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
>   error("Permissions 0%3.3o for '%s' are too open.", (u_int)st.st_mode &
>   0777, filename); error("It is recommended that your private key files
>   are NOT accessible by others."); error("This private key will be
>   ignored."); return 0; }
>
> The error message is incorrect, this is not a recommendation, it is a
>   requirement. There is no way to bypass this using SSH.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/warning-unprotected-private-key-file-override-839057/#post4132768

So I think the only solution is to mount NTFS filesystem with different permissions.

Comment: That's annoying (though I get the reasoning behind it). Any way I can read the key file from stdin or something so that SSH can't check the permissions?